# Allow all ERC20?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, erc-20, contract-debugging

So far a user can allow a smart contract or any address on Ethereum blockchain to spend their coins by calling the 'approve' function.

If I want to allow address X to spend 250 of my FabulousCoins I can call approve(x,250)

Is there a way for a user to approve an address to spend any type of coins? For example, let's say that I want to allow X to also spend 250 of my NiceCoins, 300 of my FantasticCoins and all of my GymCoins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First case: we are discussing about already deployed token. In this case:

- The allowance is a local property of any token smart contract, not a general property.
- You have to give the allowance to each user for each token.
- the maximum here is to have a script or a dedicated contract which does it for you.

Second case: we are discussing about your new tokens that you are developing. In this case:

- you can do what you want provided you write the code that realize that. If you have somewhere a multitoken ‘approve’ valid for all the token you are going to deploy, it can work.